# How to Save Query to another database in Aqua Data Studio

Tags: database

I am new to aqua data studio and have multiple databases when logging in. im running a query in another database and want to save it to another database and cant figure out where to do this. can i script this in my query or where can i go in the interface to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your query in Database 1 as a .sql file
2. Open a query window to Database 2 and Open the file and execute.
   [image]

Another option would be, in the Tree Node, navigate to the Files Tab. Under the Files tab, right click on FileSystem and then Mount the directory containing your saved SQL scripts. You can then select the saved sql file and the right click and use the Open in Current Window or Open in.. to execute the query in the Database you want.

[image]
[image]